# What's the difference between SyntaxGenerator and SyntaxFactory?

Tags: roslyn

To be more specific: `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxGenerator` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory`.

1) My understanding is that they are both part of Roslyn, and both used for generating code, is that correct? If yes, are there others in that category?

2) Is one better and/or newer than the other? I only suspect that because I found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/23).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each `SyntaxFactory` (there's one for VB and one for C#) is tightly coupled to its language. In a sense the `SyntaxFactory` is a "lower level" API which you can use to create syntax trees. You can control every syntax node, token and trivia in your tree when using a `SyntaxFactory`. This comes at a cost: It's harder to read and understand source code that uses the `SyntaxFactory` because it's very verbose.

The `SyntaxGenerator` provides a language agnostic API which can be used to create pieces of either C# or VB .NET syntax. It provides an API that is easier to use and less verbose than the `SyntaxFactory`. Note that to create a `SyntaxGenerator` we need either a `Document,` `Project`, or `Workspace`.

If you read through the [implementations](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/CodeGeneration/CSharpSyntaxGenerator.cs,42873d4cd5fb15fa) of the `SyntaxGenerator` you'll see that they are using the `SyntaxFactory` under the hood.

We can compare the two APIs when generating the following code:

```
void Method()
{
}
```

#### SyntaxFactory

```
var method = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
                    SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword)),
                    SyntaxFactory.Identifier("Method"))
                .WithBody(
                    SyntaxFactory.Block()))))
```

#### SyntaxGenerator

```
SyntaxGenerator generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(...); //We need a Document, Project or Workspace
var method = generator.MethodDeclaration("Method");
```

The generator is just a cleaner way to build up syntax trees.

Comment: Am I right, that ````SyntaxGenerator```` does not allow handling trivia? For example, I could not find a way to create a comment or preprocessor directive.

Comment: As far as I can tell you'll have to use the `SyntaxFactory` to create comments/pre-processor directives. You can use https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net to figure out exactly what to use.